# Compiling folders into Executable

Tags: c#, embedded-resource

Maybe not possible but I have an application that gets text from a bunch of text files organised in folders which are all included in my project. However I'd love to compile these text files into the exe so that I don't have to lug the folders with the application. Anyway I can do this?

The folders are in a hierarchy i.e. each folder has a txt file and image that my application uses. At the moment they are all set to build as Embedded Resources which I thought would have compiled them in but unfortunately not.

Preferably I love if there was a way I could add the folder rather than each file individually.

Comment: Nah use a zip or rar file and extract or do it properly in the installer. Good luck, I've had success with both method's - the later being more orthadox. Or even better is @Dai's approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Compilation" means something else.

Anyway, .NET confusingly uses the same terms to describe "embedded resources", which are exposed as resource streams from the assembly, and the more API-friendly resx resources which are then compiled into `.resources` files that are *also* stored as embedded resource streams.

If you want to use ResX resources in your project then go Add New Item `>` Resources (resx), then go to the Files tab and add references to your filesystem files, then build your project. You'll be able to access those files by going typing `FooResources.MyFileName` in your program's code, assuming you named your resx file `FooResources`.

Comment: Oh wow good to know thanks. Would save me a lot of work though if there was a way I could add a folder rather than have to pick out every file individually.